# Investigating Active MemInfo

Tags: linux, kernel, rhel, linux-kernel, meminfo

I am seeing high Active usage when I do a cat /proc/meminfo :

```
MemTotal: 65965328 kB
MemFree: 51640992 kB
Buffers: 1050332 kB
Cached: 8516112 kB
SwapCached: 0 kB
Active: 11512732 kB
Inactive: 1878028 kB
HighTotal: 0 kB
HighFree: 0 kB
LowTotal: 65965328 kB
LowFree: 51640992 kB
SwapTotal: 2096472 kB
SwapFree: 2096472 kB
Dirty: 51340 kB
Writeback: 0 kB
AnonPages: 3823896 kB
Mapped: 132288 kB
Slab: 876208 kB
PageTables: 15060 kB
NFS_Unstable: 0 kB
Bounce: 0 kB
CommitLimit: 35079136 kB
Committed_AS: 4945780 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed: 264384 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359473967 kB
HugePages_Total: 0
HugePages_Free: 0
HugePages_Rsvd: 0
Hugepagesize: 2048 kB
```

You can see Total Memory is 65 GB while Active usage is around 11 GB. The main java process than is running on the server isn't consuming a lot of memory ( ~ 5 % from output of top ) . I would like to know how I can dig deeper and investigate what is causing this high Active usage. I understand that this value indicates the memory actively used for buffer and page cache that cannot be reclaimed.

I am running RHEL5 kernel version 2.6.18. How can I break the "Active" usage into finer parts and identify what exactly is contributing to this high usage ?